# Roadie + Devise, can't style Devise emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

Rails 4.1.9, Ruby 2.2, Roadie 3.0.3, roadie-rails 1.0.4, devise 3.4.1, SASS

I have a shared layout that I use for both a devise mailer and a non-devise mailer. For the non-devise mailer, I explicitly set up the roadie gem. E.g:

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Roadie::Rails::Automatic

  def send_report_email
    ...
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: subject) do |format|
      format.html { render layout: 'emails' }
    end
  end

  ...

  private
  def roadie_options
    super unless Rails.env.test?
  end
end
```

This is the head of the layout:

```
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag('mailers/shared') %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag(yield :stylesheet_path) %>
</head>
```

For my custom mailer, I provide a stylesheet_path, but do not in my devise views. However, even though the mailers/shared css file gets applied for the custom mailer, it does not for the devise mailer.

In my application.rb:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::Mailer.layout 'emails'
end
```

I have also set up mailer_previews, and while the styling is applied for both stylesheets to the custom_mailer, no styles are applied to my devise mailer view.

I did restart my server. I tried following the instructions [here](http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/how-to-style-emails-with-rails-and-roadie/). But I presume I'm missing something somewhere. Is there some additional option I need to add to a devise controller or do some monkey patching to get this to work? Any ideas?

P.S. I wanted to tag this with `roadie` but I don't have enough reputation. Feel free to add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing an initializer that monkey patches Devise. You can add a `devise_mailer_overrides.rb` into `config/initializers` with the following code, and it appears to work:

```
Devise::Mailer.class_eval do
  self.asset_host = nil
  include Roadie::Rails::Automatic

  private

  def roadie_options
    super unless Rails.env.test?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When roadie_options is not needed this could be a case:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::Mailer.layout 'mailer'
  Devise::Mailer.send(:include, Roadie::Rails::Automatic)
end
```